# How to increment the key in an Array - PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say that I have the following array :

```
Array ( [0] => Jonny Cash [1] => Robert Smith )
```

How can I increment the array key in order to get something like this:

```
Array ( [1] => Jonny Cash [2] => Robert Smith )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do that something like that would be necessary? The two arrays above are functionally identical.

Comment: I'm trying to use the array key as an id later on to get a record from a DB.

Comment: Can you change the way you create the array initially?

Comment: The array_flip() method breaks if any of the elements are not unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push a null on to the front of the array and then delete it:

```
array_unshift($list, null);
unset($list[0]);
```

Comment: Note: This doesn't work unless your keys are contiguous. I.e., you have to have 0,1,2 and not 0,1,3.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to make an existing array have a 1-based index, just add a fake entry at 0 and remove it:

```
// Assuming $array = Array ( [0] => Jonny Cash [1] => Robert Smith );

array_unshift($array, "fake");
unset($array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(1 => 'Jonny Cash', 2 => 'Robert Smith');
print_r($array);
```

**Output:**

> Array ( [1] => Jonny Cash [2] => Robert Smith )